# Allow timestream:describe execution

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-timestream

I am writing up a AWS lambda function that will crunch some data and add it to a AWS timestream table.
I get this error:

> lambda-foobar is not authorized to perform: timestream:DescribeEndpoints because no
> identity-based policy allows the timestream:DescribeEndpoints action

I do not see any permission sets for AWS timestream. Should I create a new IAM role that has write permissions to AWS timestream and assign that role to my lambda as well?
I am new to the world of Identity management in AWS and trying to wrap my head around configuring and attributing permissions.

Comment: It seems DescribeEndpoints because it searches widely across Timestream, needs blanket permissions and not just permissions on the database and table that you're working with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

During their executions, AWS lambda functions utilize an IAM role which determines which actions the lambda function is authorized to perform. This role is known as an *Execution role*.

You can find the role under "Permissions" in the "Configuration" pane.

For the API action that you are trying to run, you will need to make sure that the IAM role has the following policy included:

```
{
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": [
    "timestream:DescribeEndpoints"
  ],
  "Resource": "*"
}
```

You can find more information on permissions for AWS lambda in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-permissions.html?icmpid=docs_lambda_help).

Comment: This is very helpful. What tripped me up is that I assigned the permission to the database and the table. It turns out that `DescribeEndpoints` needs to have wildcard permissions on everything for this to work.